# I am getting 404 from server but i know that API exists in the back end (node.js)

Tags: reactjs

I have a Node.js file in which I am creating node APIs to interact with the client side (react). It is working fine with existing APIs, however when I create new APIs, server is throwing 404 error.

P.S: It is working absolutely fine in localhost

```
 app.post('/getMarket', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("=========== GET MARKET =============");               
 });
```

Console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) getMarket:1

Any idea how can we solve this?

Comment: Please format the code correctly.

Comment: Whats the full url path you're trying to connect to? `/getMarket` isn't the full url.

Comment: I have hosted my node on the same port as the client application. I have other two APIs working but i dont know why am i getting 404 for the ones i am creating now.

Comment: hmm, I assume your other two API's also just have the URL as `/<some-service>` in the app.post?

Comment: I ask this, because I have a REACT app running locally, and a Java web service running locally as well, and for the REACT to post to the back end java server I had to put the full url in the $.post which was the url of the web service `http://<mydomain>:8080/<service>` and it works fine.

Comment: yep... thats why i am not able to figure out the reason and its working fine on my local machine

Comment: Yeah true but here i am not calling any other service, i am doing all the processing just here.

Comment: How are you testing against remote host? Are you sure the remote host has the updated server running?

Comment: If you're sure that your server is running, I suggest you to check the error log in the server instead

Comment: Or how about to simply write something like `app.get('/')` and return a string 'hello world' and test `http://<mydomain>:8080/` in the browser to see if it works